# Vue.js can I import a module in an e2e test ? Syntax error on import

Tags: vue.js, nightwatch.js, e2e-testing

I am running my e2e test using NightWatch framework

In  a test, I need to check a browser displayed value to be reset to a defined  initial value, set as a constant exported from a config.js file

but I get a SYNTAX error , is it not accepted ?

```
Starting selenium server... started - PID:  49634
There was an error while starting the test runner:
../test/e2e/specs/test.js:4
import { WORKING_TIME } from '@/config';
^^^^^^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token import    at createScript (vm.js:74:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:116:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:537:28)
    at loader (../node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/../node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:507:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:470:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:462:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:517:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
```

**config.js**

```
let coeff = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'testing' ? 0.5 : 1
export const WORKING_TIME = coeff * 60
```

**e2e/test.js**

```
import { WORKING_TIME } from '@/config'

module.exports = { 
    'check STOP event': (browser) => {
    const devServer = browser.globals.devServerURL
    browser.url(devServer).waitForElementVisible('#app', 5000)
    browser.click('[title=start]').waitForElementVisible('i.toggle-volume', 5000)

    // CLICK on STOP button
    browser.click('[title=stop]').pause(1000)
    ...
    // Check timer is reset
    const leftPad = (str, length = 10) => {
      return `${' '.repeat(length)}${str}`
    }
    const min = Math.floor(WORKING_TIME / 60)
    const sec = WORKING_TIME % 60
    const initialTimer = leftPad(min, 2) + ':' + leftPad(sec, 2)
    browser.expect.element('.my-timer').text.to.equal(initialTimer)
    browser.end()
  }
}
```

Comment: it looks like you have a problem in ES6.
Make sure to transpile before running tests using babel

Comment: thanks Omran ! got it right now , you put me on tracks.. see my own answer

Answer (score 0):

As @Omran mentioned , I had problem w ES6 transpiring ..

1 - need to insert before the import ( and also write a correct path...)

**e2e/test.js**

```
require('babel-core/register')
import { WORKING_TIME } from '../../../config'
```

2 - e2e test runner.js is setting :

```
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'testing'
```

I should add it into .babelrc

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": [
    ["env", {
      "modules": false,
      "targets": {
        "browsers": ["> 1%", "last 2 versions", "not ie <= 8"]
      }
    }],
    "stage-2"
  ],
  "plugins": ["transform-runtime"],
  "env": {
    "test": {
      "presets": ["env", "stage-2"],
      "plugins": ["istanbul"]
    },
    "testing": {
      "presets": ["env", "stage-2"],
      "plugins": ["istanbul"]
    }
  }
}
```